# Trying to install GNUPlot on Mac OS Catalina... ../term/lua.trm:107:10: fatal error: 'lua.h' file not found

Tags: macos, lua, operating-system, gnuplot, macos-catalina

I'm using Mac OS Catalina to install gnuplot which is a dependency for a java based application and I'm receiving FATAL ERROR: 'lua.h' file not found

```
#./configure --with-readline=builtin

#make                     # build the program and documentation

make[4]: *** [term.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

#make check               # run unit tests to confirm successful build

../term/lua.trm:107:10: fatal error: 'lua.h' file not found
#include <lua.h>
         ^~~~~~~

1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [term.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [check] Error 2
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: well looks like you're missing a file. are you?

Comment: Probably you need to have Lua installed prior to installing GNUplot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a package manager like HomeBrew (http://brew.sh) which deals with all the dependencies (like Lua) when installing.  Is there a reason you need to build it yourself like this?